# How can I get Python to read output data from another process (in this case TeraTerm) and check it is correct?

Tags: python-3.11, teraterm

I have no idea where to begin.

I am trying to automate data reading testing in TeraTerm (pass data specifically).

I know what the expected output from TeraTerm should be, so is there a way I can get Python to read and check the data from TeraTerm against the payload I define as correct in Python itself?

Unfortunately i am quite new to python, and coding in general.

I was hoping to have some way of getting Python to scan TeraTerm for the desired payload (using loops perhaps) and then cross reference this against the values i set as True.

Is this doable?

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever finds this and is wondering, I did manage a work around.

I created a log file for teraterm, then after all testing was complete I simply compared the log against a pre-made .txt file containing all the correct outputs.

```
''''
# this isa snippet after booting teraterm and setting up a new connection
def write_TTlog():
    with pyautogui.hold('alt'):
        pyautogui.press(['f'])
    pyautogui.press('l')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.typewrite('test.log')
    pyautogui.press('return')
    time.sleep(1)    # Logging mode turned on
    pyautogui.press('left')
    pyautogui.press('return')
    time.sleep(1)
write_TTlog()
''''
```

---

```
''''
check = filecmp.cmp('I:\\Test\\TeraTerm Logs\\test.log', Test_file)
if check == True:
    print('\nAll Payloads match')
elif check == False:
    print('\nPayloads do not match')
''''
```